# How to get data into datagrid using dataset?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

whats wrong with this code ? i want populate all users in datagridview1 but datagirdview showing nothing .

```
private void button4_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = db.todosUsuario("select usuario from usuarios");
}

//DB class
public DataSet todosUsuario(string query)
{
    DataSet dt= new DataSet();
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(MysqlConnect());
        cnn.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, cnn);
        da.Fill(dt,"Usuario");
        cnn.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ed)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ed.ToString());
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the DataGridView to a DataSet.
In a dataset there are multiple tables so you need to specify which table should be shown in the DataGrid using the DataMember property. (Yes also when you have only one in the tables collection)

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true; 
DataSet ds = db.todosUsuario("select usuario from usuarios"); 
dataGridView1.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName;
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

You could change the code binding to a single table

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

The following may be considered to be a big comment rather than an answer, which is why I've made the answer CW.

There are a number of issues with the code as presented. These represent good habits to lose early.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = db.todosUsuario("select usuario from usuarios");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Exception");
    }
}

//DB class
public DataSet todosUsuario(string query)
{
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(MysqlConnect()))
    {
        cnn.Open();
        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, cnn))
        {
            da.Fill(dt, "Usuario");
        }
        cnn.Close();
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Both the connection and data adapter objects implement `IDisposable`, and should therefore be wrapped in `using` blocks.

Furthermore, it's not a good idea to have every method concern itself with catching exceptions, especially when the only "handling" you can do is to display an error message. In particular, by placing a `MessageBox.Show` call in your DB class, you are requiring it to be run in a Windows Forms application, and violating Separation of Concerns.

Instead, I suggest you place the exception handling at a very high level in your code. In the case of a Windows Forms application, it may be best to keep your exception handling in your event handlers, so as not to permit exceptions to "escape" from the events. Even better would be to do such last-resort handling globally, but I've never done that in a WinForms application so cannot show you how.

Comment: What on earth does exception handling have to do with the question?

Comment: The code posted by the OP showed an example of bad exception handling.